# How to download a file to $env:temp directory using powershell from cmd console?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I can download a file to a constant location from cmd console using powershell like this

```
C:\Users\Weijun>powershell -command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://example.com/example.zip', 'D:\example.zip')"
```

but i need to download it to system temp directory,using the powershell variable `$env:temp`,the following doesn't work.(variable not expanded in single-quote)

```
powershell -command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://example.com/example.zip', '$env:temp\example.zip')"
```

how to pass variable as parameter in method invoke?

**UPDATE:** it is a typo for `$env:temp:`,I amend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

From *outside* of PowerShell (`cmd.exe` - Command Prompt or batch file), use *escaped double-quoted strings* - `\"...\"` - inside the overall command string - `"..."` - passed to `powershell -command` for strings that need *interpolation* (e.g., expansion of variable references such as `$env:temp`):

```
powershell -command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://example.com/example.zip', \"$env:temp\example.zip\")"
```

---

You not only need to fix the incidental problem that Nkosi points out - removing the extraneous `:` at the end of `$env:temp:` - but you must *generally* either ***not quote* the path at all (*argument* syntax)**, or **use *escaped double quotes* (*expression* syntax or values with shell metacharacters)** - *single*-quoted strings don't work, because PowerShell treats their content as a *literal* and won't expand the environment-variable reference.<sup>[1]</sup>

<sup>For a description of **PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes** - argument syntax vs. expression syntax - see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx).</sup>

**Simplified examples:**

- ***Without* quoting** (*argument* syntax):

  ```
  c:\>powershell.exe -noprofile -command "write-output $env:temp\example.zip"
  C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\example.zip
  ```
- With **double-quoting** (*expression* syntax or if the value contains shell metacharacters such as `,` or `|`):

  ```
  c:\>powershell.exe -noprofile -command "write-output \"$env:temp\example.zip\""
  C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Temp\example.zip
  ```

Note: When **called from the *outside*, PowerShell requires embedded `"` chars. to be escaped as `\"`** - unlike *inside* PowerShell, where `` `" `` must be used.

**Applied to your command: *with* (escaped) double-quoting**, which is needed, because you're using **.NET *method* syntax**, which is parsed with *expression* syntax:

```
powershell -command "(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://example.com/example.zip', \"$env:temp\example.zip\")"
```

---

<sup>[1] If you run the same command *from PowerShell*, you won't see the problem, because the command *as a whole* is enclosed in `"..."`, which means that the *current* PowerShell session will expand `$env:temp` - *before* it is passed to `powershell.exe`.

However, when called from `cmd.exe`, this interpolation is NOT applied - hence the need to either omit quoting or use embedded (escaped) double-quoting.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Invoke-WebRequest` with `-OutFile`:

```
powershell -command "Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://example.com/file-to-get.txt' -OutFile $env:temp\file-to-get.txt"
```

NB this requires PowerShell 3.0 (if I remember correctly).